# EE6 gif upload removes animation?

Tags: file-uploads, files, ee6

Recently updated to EE6.4 and now all of a sudden any uploaded filename.gif (GIF) image is manipulated and the animations are removed.

Example being, uploaded a 404kb gif with animation which was converted to a 101kb gif without animation.

Sftp manual uploads do not cause this so I'm certain it isn't a server/host issue. Also I know this was not the case with EE5.

General settings are set to use GD2 and not GD, also this server is running php8.

I'm assuming that when EE is creating a thumbnail (which doesnt need animatio) it also somehow loses the original file being uploaded and just uploads a the temp non-aminated one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known/accepted bug with EE6](https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues/2639).

So far there is no suggestion from Packet Tide about when the bug might be fixed, but if you read the Github comments you can see a working / workable solution described (but it requires you modify the code for an EE Image processing library).

Alternatively there is a work around - use an FTP type program to upload the gif to the appropriate Files directory within your EE setup, and then from within the EE CP "[synchronise](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/file-manager/file-manager.html)" the Files directory - this will update the EE database with details of your GIF image but won't cause the image to be overwritten by the upload process...

HTH

Comment: Dang, that link did not pop up in my google searches! Thanks for that! Unfortunately i cannot rely on ftp uploads as there are many users whom do not have that access/ability. Hence EE's directory upload feature. Ill read into the working solutions you mentioned in github. Again Thanks!

Comment: A fix for this will be going live in the 6.4.5 release. Which should be 02/07/2023 https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/pull/2805